# react-native run-android Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I am learing  react-native,i got this error when i used command 'react-native run-android' on windows 10

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'demo'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.3.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/1.3.1/gradle-core-1.3.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/1.3.1/gradle-core-1.3.1.jar'.
            > peer not authenticated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I'm tired,I'll be appreciate for you helping me!

Comment: First time I see this. Can you fetch the binary from a browser? https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/1.3.1/gradle-core-1.3.1.jar

Comment: Google gives: https://www.google.com/search?q=gradle+peer+not+authenticated

Comment: @MartinKonicek as you say,I can't get it!,

Comment: Are you on a VPN / behind some proxy at your office or school maybe?

Comment: @MartinKonicek  I fixed it after set proxy,thank you!

Comment: I am facing same problem, how did you solve it. I am running on my organisations proxy